# Inbox message cannot be removed

Tags: support, notifications, global-inbox

in my inbox in the top-right corner *profile section* I have this message:
[image: missing Inbox message]

But when I click on it, that answer has been removed.
How can I get rid of that message?

Comment: Why do you need to? It's never been possible to remove messages from your inbox.

Comment: Is it that you're wondering why your inbox notification badge shows (1)? If so, it's because of the election notification, not the answer notification you're asking about. You can clear that election notification by clicking on it, clicking on the mail-looking icon at the right of the notification line, or clicking "Mark all as read" at the top-right of the notification popup/dropdown.